# Using FIRST_VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is some example data:

```
create table #Baseline (Document varchar(40), Type varchar(10), Location int)
insert into #Baseline values
('Pump Telemetry',  'None', NULL),
('Clinical Documentation',  'None', NULL),
('Demographics',    'None', NULL),
('Patient Insurance',   'None', NULL),
('Insurance Card Secondary',    'None', NULL),
('Treatment Plan of Care',  'None', NULL),
('Override Medication Interaction', 'None', NULL),
('Override Medication Change',  'None', NULL),
('Override Pump System Complication',   'None', NULL),
('Override MRI Appointment',    'None', NULL)


create table #Data (Document varchar(40), Type varchar(10), Location int)
insert into #Data values
('Pump Telemetry',  'Hardstop', 30656),
('Pump Telemetry',  'Hardstop', 1279396),
('Clinical Documentation',  'Hardstop', 1279396),
('Demographics',    'Softstop', 30656),
('Treatment Plan of Care',  'Hardstop', 1279396)
```

What I'm needing is a query that will assign the `Location` the right value when it is NULL. Right now, I'm only able to get results that are partially what I want, such as these 2 screenshots:

[image]

[image]

But what I need is for those NULL's to be filled in with their corresponding `Location` value, to get something like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm partially there by using `FIRST_VALUE` but I think I'm just not quite grasping how to use it. When I add both of these `Location` values to my WHERE clause, it only shows one of them rather than both. I would expect to see 10 rows for each `Location`, initially populating  the `Type` column with the correct value in the #Data table and then backfilling the remaining rows with the value of 'None', per the #Baseline table.

I'm assuming I'm missing a proper designation of the Partition By argument of the function, but nothing I've tried works.

---

**EDIT1:** Let me see if I can clear up some apparent ambiguity. So right now, I'm looking at the results of #Data. This table represents what I currently am working with as a final result in my main query. The problem is that this data set is missing the other rows. So for example, in #Data, LocationId 30656 only shows Pump Telemetry and Demographics, with a Type value of Hardstop and Softstop respectively. I need another 8 rows added to these 2 rows, but these 8 should only be the missing Document values with a Type = None and backfilling the Location with the Location that is present in #Data (30656, in this example). But this will need to be a dynamic solution that will apply to any Location value that may arise.

Comment: What defines the : corresponding Location value for each documentTypeName/hardstopName?  PUt another way, why are locationID 30656 assigned to all "none" records and 1279396 assigned to all the other none records ? It looks like Demographas gets both depending on the dataset...  So I don't see any rule to determine which is assigned when.  It almost looks like whatever location is assigned to "HardSTop" gets assigned to all records in the data set... without rules though I don't see how this can be answered

Comment: By default, the #Data table holds what exists as a hard rule. So the locationID is set to each HardstopName there. However, I need to also display the remaining DocumentTypeName's (from #Baseline) to show them as 'None', but also have the ClinicLocationId backfilled as well.

Comment: Why do you have two different datasets in your expected results?   Why isn't pump telemetry only listed in the first data set (Baseline)... not enough infomration to address this problem as presented.

Comment: There are 2 different datasets illustrating the results for each LocationId...

Comment: so two seperate queries?  One for each location wher elocatoin is in the where clause?  Yeah I don't get it sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can assume:

1. You want 1 dataset
2. You want for each location the list of all records in baseline to be associated to that location
3. the type from data to be displayed when present, otherwise the type from baseline
4. This means; for each location, all of the entries in baseline will exist, those records will have the locationID the same on all those reocrds, and the type will be the type from #data when exists, or whatever the type is from baseline if not.  So if one adds a record to data that doesn't exist in location, it will not show up at all. If one adds a baseline, it will exist in all locations from then on until removed.  ([Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/6uXTwOhF) I added 2 lines to your data to illustrate)

To do this we:

- Generate a distinct list of locations
- cross join that list to your baseline so all baselines exist for each location
- left join in datset to get the type for each baseline that exists
- coalese in the baseline type in if no type exists in dataset

Maybe: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0qgF2Pcj)

```
With DistinctLocation as (SELECT Distinct Location from #Data)
SELECT B.Document, coalesce(D.Type, B.Type) as Type, DL.Location
  From DistinctLocation DL
CROSS JOIN #Baseline B
LEFT JOIN #Data D
 on D.Document = B.Document
and D.Location = DL.Location
ORDER BY DL.Location, D.Type desc, B.Document
```

Giving you:

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+
|             Document              |   Type   | Location |
+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+
| Demographics                      | Softstop |    30656 |
| Pump Telemetry                    | Hardstop |    30656 |
| Clinical Documentation            | None     |    30656 |
| Insurance Card Secondary          | None     |    30656 |
| Override Medication Change        | None     |    30656 |
| Override Medication Interaction   | None     |    30656 |
| Override MRI Appointment          | None     |    30656 |
| Override Pump System Complication | None     |    30656 |
| Patient Insurance                 | None     |    30656 |
| Treatment Plan of Care            | None     |    30656 |
| Clinical Documentation            | Hardstop |  1279396 |
| Pump Telemetry                    | Hardstop |  1279396 |
| Treatment Plan of Care            | Hardstop |  1279396 |
| Demographics                      | None     |  1279396 |
| Insurance Card Secondary          | None     |  1279396 |
| Override Medication Change        | None     |  1279396 |
| Override Medication Interaction   | None     |  1279396 |
| Override MRI Appointment          | None     |  1279396 |
| Override Pump System Complication | None     |  1279396 |
| Patient Insurance                 | None     |  1279396 |
+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This is close. The only issue is that it is, as a byproduct of the cross join, associating the Document and Type from each Location, to each Location. For example, 30656 (per the #Data table) does not have a Type value of Hardstop for Document value Treatment Plan of Care. So my 2 datasets in my expected results, I essentially need to union those together.

Comment: error on copy and paste and iterations while trying to get to what I assumed you wanted.  The left join needed to have the d.location = DL.location added or we replicated duplicate Documents from data on the left join.  and then when I updated the result set I missed something... Look again

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I see what you're doing, it's a different approach than how I was going at it, but it makes sense.

Comment: THe problme with a left join is you'll only get 1 record even if you have 2 locations.  So the cross join is needed or you'd have to use a procedure and loop through each location.  Since you wanted a dynamic answer; I thought this would work best  FIrst we have to generate a baseline record for each location which is what the cross join accomplishes.  WIthout it you'd be "missing" baselines for a location or have to do each location in it's own query and union the data; but that didn't seem dynamic to me

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right. I only mentioned my method because it was so clearly wrong lol this is fantastic, I hope this sticks with me

Comment: Just a common design pattern you'll see if you play around with SQL long enough.  Anytime you have to "Create missing records" it's likely a loop or cross join will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think you just need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.Document, COALESCE(d.Type,b.Type) AS HardstopName, d.Location
  FROM #Baseline b
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #Data d
      ON b.Document = D.Document
```

| Document | HardstopName | Location | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pump Telemetry | Hardstop | 30656 | None |
| Pump Telemetry | Hardstop | 1279396 | None |
| Clinical Documentation | Hardstop | 1279396 | None |
| Demographics | Softstop | 30656 | None |
| Patient Insurance | None |  | None |
| Insurance Card Secondary | None |  | None |
| Treatment Plan of Care | Hardstop | 1279396 | None |
| Override Medication Interaction | None |  | None |
| Override Medication Change | None |  | None |
| Override Pump System Complication | None |  | None |
| Override MRI Appointment | None |  | None |

Some of the rows still do not have a **Location** as there's no corresponding row in the data table. We're using a `COALESCE` to find the first non null value from the columns provided.

If you can provide more detail on where the location values for the missing rows comes from it might be possible to tweak this to include those, too.